# How can I discard 10*10 pixels from WebGL alternately

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have drawn a square using webgl. I want to make the square checkered board. So What I need to do is I need to discard some 10*10 pixels alternately from the square. How can I use

```
gl_FragCoord.x and gl_FragCoord.x
```

To achieve this? Or is there any easy idea?

Comment: What does "discard" mean in this case? Clear or fill it by some color?

Comment: discard actually clears and doesn't render for the specified location

Comment: I'd just use multiple squares instead of one.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4694608/868679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING: untested.

You could do math on the fragment shader to create the checker board pattern. First do integer division of x and y by 10 and you get the tile coordinates, lets call it i and j. Then add i and j together. If the result of that is odd, discard the fragments, else if even, keep the fragments.